# What is this component in the picture (brass and plastic)?

Tags: components

What is the component in the picture?

[image]

Comment: Not the best photo for ID, maybe some other views as in from the front and the back.  Also, recommend you consider doing an image search with Google.  Go to images.google.com and use the entry box selected for file upload.

Comment: [Trimmer Capacitor](https://www.google.com/search?q=trimmer+capacitor&rlz=1C1MSIM_enUS575US575&oq=trimmer+capacitor)

Comment: @brhans:  That's the correct answer.  Want to make a real answer out of that comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sprague trimmer capacitor, rotating-vane type.  Max value maybe 65pF, maybe 100pF.   Good for about 100V max.

Comment: From the size it is likely to be around 25pF. However, being open, they accumulate dust, moisture and oil and the capacitance will change. Also, the polypropylene/mica sheets may get damaged due to temperature changes due to soldering, or even simply in storage.

Comment: @Indraneel perhaps right.  See digikey photos, count number of layers for various values.  In the OP photo, it appears to be the 0.43" type (the diameter.)   100V rating isn't very accurate when slight dust is involved: we've had several of these fail catastrophically in amplifier gate circuits, only while being adjusted with power and signal applied (30VDC, plus 10Vpp of RF.)  Save your expensive rf mosfets, momentarily power down before tweaking the value!